# &nbsp text not handled by the lxml

Tags: python, lxml

My html file has the following line

```
<tr><td>$nbsp;</td><tr>
```

But when I do the parsing with lxml:

```
from lxml import tree as ET
tree = ET.parse("file.html")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3310, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72517)
File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105979)
File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106278)
File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105277)
File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:100227)
File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94350)
File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95786)
File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94853)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'nbsp' not defined, line 14, column 159
```

Comment: One might argue this to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974909/xml-non-breaking-space

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Use `lxml.html`, not `lxml.etree`, for HTML.](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) `&nbsp;` is legitimately not predefined in XML, but it's available for HTML. Thus:

```
>>> lxml.html.fromstring('''<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><tr>''')
<Element div at 0x10a7a5e68>
```

...works properly.

---

Alternately, you can use the XML equivalent for `&nbsp;`, which is `&#160;`, in your document, or you can declare a `DOCTYPE` in your XML file and include `<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">` in its contents.